# And function with SHL FUNCTION

Tags: assembly, x86

,,,,,01011011b and 11000111b ;;;I am trying to display the results as an ascii string of binary digits.
I am using the shl instruction to isolate each bit and jump on carry. All that I can get to print is garble. Can someone lend a hand?

```
    .stack 100h
    .model small
    .386

    .data

    str1  db  20 dup(?)
    lstring EQU 9

    .code

main: 
    mov ax, @data                ; initialize DS
    mov ds, ax
    mov cx, lstring
L1: 
    mov al,01011011b                     
    and al,11000111b             
    shl al, 1
    mov str1, al
    mov ax, 8
    loop L1

    mov ax, 4000h                   ;   dos service to display...
    mov bx, 1                   ;   to screen
    mov cx, lstring             ;   number of bytes
    mov dx, OFFSET str1         ;   where to get data
    int 21h

    MOV AH, 4CH                 ; return control to DOS
    INT 21H

end main
```

Comment: _"I am using the shl instruction to isolate each bit and jump on carry."_ There's no jump on carry in the code you've posted. Why is the `AND` computation taking place for every iteration of the loop, instead of just once? And what's the `mov ax, 8` supposed to do?

Comment: Yes, the whole loop is basically invariant, and the result after 9 iterations is no different from the first one.

Answer (score 0):

You should address your output string **str1** dynamically, using a register. DI is the best choice:

```
  mov di,str1 ; Address of the first byte of output string.
  mov cx,8 ; Number of bits to print.
L1:
  shl al,1 ; Put the most significant bit of AL to CF.
  mov dl,'0' ; Output ASCII character.
  adc dl,0  ; Change it from '0' to '1' when CF was set.
  mov [di],dl ; Store the ASCII character to output string.
  inc di ; Let di point to the next character.
  loop L1 ; Repeat with remaining bits.
```